# fail to get Facebook SDK for IOS source from git

Tags: git, facebook-ios-sdk

i just try to get the sources from git but im getting this error

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
Cloning into 'facebook-ios-sdk'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

what i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run the `git clone` command with `sudo`, and hence `git` tries to use the public key associated with the `root` account instead of your user. The error `Permission denied (publickey).` could be due to any of the reasons, some or most of which are explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) already.

Since you've not stated why you really want to use `sudo`, I'm assuming you just tried it with `sudo` by mistake. Give the same command a try without `sudo` and check if it works.

```
git clone git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
```

Also try running `ssh -T -v git@github.com` and `sudo ssh -T -v git@github.com` to see more debug messages on why you're getting the public key denied error message.